# How to use shift() after push() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

So I start with my current code

```
var lineChartCanvas1 = $("#lineChart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
var lineChart1 = new Chart(lineChartCanvas1);

var x = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  x.push(data[i]['Timestamp'])
}

var y1 = [];
for (var j=0; j<data.length; j++){
  y1.push(data[j]['TotalStudent'])
}

var lineChartData1 = {
  labels: x,
  datasets: [
    {
      fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: y1
    },]};

var lineChartOptions = ...

lineChart1.Line(lineChartData1, lineChartOptions);
```

And this is the assumed data in table form

```
Timestamp | TotalStudent
   123    |     456
   789    |     321
   451    |     100
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Currently with this code I can draw a line chart. 
Then I thought of adding a pagination to the line chart but could not found any example for that.

After some googling, I found the `shift()` function and I am thinking to write it like this

```
var x = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  x.push(data[i]['Timestamp'])
  x.shift(data[j]['Timestamp'])
}
```

where I thought it will automatically remove the first element and continue with adding the next element at the back but this actually a disaster.

It did not show any timestamp label on x-axis.

My question is, is it possible to do something like this? Using `shift()` after `push` in the same function. It is like mimicking the pagination style but it only triggered when user click on `refresh page` or something.

Of course it has a really bad effect to the user as they can't access the early data once the refresh the page.

Now, I also think to add another `for` loop on top of the `data.length` loop but could not figured out what variable should I use for the loop

If somebody has any suggestion for pagination instead using `shift()` and adding another `for` loop, I really love to know that.

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: please add the original array with objects and the wanted result.

Comment: Why not use Array.slice? No need for a loop when doing pagination.